# Azure Function 3.0 Service Bus triggered sometimes throws Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus.MessageLockLostException

Tags: azure, .net-core, azure-functions, azureservicebus

I know Azure Functions 3.0 is in preview but so we better catch up bugs sooner than later.

My function is triggered by Service Bus queue messages. In my case, I have 2 processes sending a message every 15 minutes. So the Azure Func is not really busy.

Most of the time there are no problems, but about 2 times a day I get these errors:

> Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus.MessageLockLostException:
>      at Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus.Core.MessageReceiver+d__99.MoveNext (Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus, Version=4.1.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7e34167dcc6d6d8c)
>      at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
>      at Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus.RetryPolicy+d__19.MoveNext (Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus, Version=4.1.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7e34167dcc6d6d8c)
>      at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
>      at Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus.RetryPolicy+d__19.MoveNext (Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus, Version=4.1.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7e34167dcc6d6d8c)
>      at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
>      at Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus.Core.MessageReceiver+d__68.MoveNext (Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus, Version=4.1.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7e34167dcc6d6d8c)
>      at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
>      at Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus.MessageReceivePump+d__16.MoveNext (Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus, Version=4.1.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7e34167dcc6d6d8c)

I changed message TTL = 30 min, Lock duration = 2 min, Max Delivery Count = 10 (default). So these settings shouldn't affect anything I believe.

Can anyone tell me why do I get these errors and how to fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`MessageLockLostException` indicates that your Function has taken longer than the defined `LockDuration` in the queue to process the message. You could increase the time up to 5 minutes, but that still might occur. I would recommend to log execution time and analyze how long did it take your Function when the exception is thrown.

Side note: `TimeToLive` and `MaxDeliveryCount` are not related to this issue.

Comment: Our function occasionally takes > 5 mins to run and we have set the lockduration to 5 min. Is there a recommended way to auto renew the lock without causing the exception to throw? We use Azure Durable Functions 3.0. We do not use BrokeredMessage or complete the message ourselves using message receiver.

Comment: Suggest you raise it as a separate question with details rather that tag along in comments of somewhat unrelated question. While exception is the same, the circumstances are clearly different. Cheers.