# Azure Function (Service Bus Trigger) System.OperationCanceledException

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-topics

I have an Azure Function (.net 6.0) that receives messages from Services Bus. 99% of the messages process fine but every now and then I get the System.OperationCanceledException in Application Insights.

Call Stack:

```
System.OperationCanceledException:
   at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.ServiceBus.MessageProcessor.CompleteProcessingMessageAsync (Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.ServiceBus, Version=5.5.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=92742159e12e44c8)
   at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.ServiceBus.Listeners.ServiceBusListener+<ProcessMessageAsync>d__26.MoveNext (Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.ServiceBus, Version=5.5.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=92742159e12e44c8)
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus.ServiceBusProcessor+<OnProcessMessageAsync>d__104.MoveNext (Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus, Version=7.8.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=92742159e12e44c8)
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus.ReceiverManager+<OnMessageHandler>d__19.MoveNext (Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus, Version=7.8.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=92742159e12e44c8)
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus.ReceiverManager+<ProcessOneMessage>d__15.MoveNext (Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus, Version=7.8.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=92742159e12e44c8)
```

Call Stack (Just my code):

```
System.OperationCanceledException
Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.ServiceBus.MessageProcessor.CompleteProcessingMessageAsync
[external code]
Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus.ServiceBusProcessor+<OnProcessMessageAsync>d__104.MoveNext
[external code]
Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus.ReceiverManager+<OnMessageHandler>d__19.MoveNext
[external code]
Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus.ReceiverManager+<ProcessOneMessage>d__15.MoveNext
```

[image: Application Insights]

Looking at the FormattedMessage: It seems to have failed on ProcessMessageCallback. I looked it up and the only information I could find was this: Errors thrown from the user's processMessage callback passed to subscribe.

The failed method is: Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus.ServiceBusProcessor+d__104.MoveNext

To me it looks like this is a ServiceBus issue and not my code. I am using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.ServiceBus v5.5.1.

Has anyone else experienced this issue or know how to resolve this?

Update:
I've added exception handling in the hopes to capture more information:

```
    catch (OperationCanceledException ex)
    {
        throw new OperationCanceledException(ex.Message);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw new ApplicationException(ex.Message);
    }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58974401/azure-function-3-0-service-bus-triggered-sometimes-throws-microsoft-azure-servic?rq=1

Comment: No, that thread is for MessageLockException.

Comment: Is it possible that your function code is throwing an OperationCanceledException? Are you binding to the CancellationToken in your function and passing it to another method?

Comment: @JoshLove thank for your message. I'm not binding the function to the CancellationToken. Should I?

Comment: @JoshLove  I'm receiving and processing a single message at one time so I didn't feel the need for a CancellationToken. But now I have added exception handling in the hopes to capture more information on the exception. I have updated my post.

Comment: Are you using any external libraries in your code? Other than Microsoft's?

Comment: I don't think it is necessary to bind to cancellation token - I was just trying to speculate as to how the OperationCanceledException was being generated. Could you share the code for your function?

Answer (score 0):

This can happen when the function host is attempting to stop or recycle an instance, for example during scale-in. If the function is running on 3 instances and is scaling in to run on 2 instances, the instance being "killed" will get a cancellation.